# AD Sync scenarios

Tags: user-profile, people-search, active-directory-import

We have three different types of users in our company:

- Type A: user is working in our company, user has an AD account which he is using for login on windows and on sharepoint, user must be find in peoplesearch on sharepoint
- Type B: user is working in our company, user must not login on windows or sharepoint, user must be find in peoplesearch on sharepoint
- Type C: user leave company, user must not login on windows or sharepoint, user should not be found in peoplesearch on sharepoint

Current situation:
Type A-Users have an AD-Account, Type B-Users have no AD-Acount, Type C-User has a disabled AD-Account. License is only paied for users of Type A.

Possible target situation:
Type A-Users have an AD-Account in OU "Company".
Type B-Users have a disabled AD-Account in OU "Company".
Type C-Users have a disabled AD-Account in OU "EX-Company".

The sharepoint AD-Sync consider all users of OU "Company" (incl. the disabled accounts).

When a user of Type A leaves the company, the user account will be moved from OU "Company" to "EX-Company" and the user account will be disabled.
When a user of type B leaves the company, the user account will be moved from OU "Company" to "EX-Company" (account is still disabled).

Would this work?
What are the problems?

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter/exclude the disabled user accounts from AD during import to SharePoint User Profile Service, follow the below steps

- Go to Central Administration >> Application Management >> Manage
  service applications
- Click on the User Profile Service Application
- Under Synchronization group, click on Configure Synchronization
  Connections
- Click on the connection you want to filter and select ‘Edit
  Connection Filters’ from the drop down menu
- In Edit Connection Filters page, Select the properties as below to
  filter the disabled users
- Attribute : userAccountControls; Operator: Bit on Equal; Filter : 2
- Click Add to include the exclusion filter

For more details refer the links below,

http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/Filter-disabled-user-accounts-from-AD-to-SharePoint.html

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spses/archive/2014/04/14/sharepoint-2013-adimport-is-not-cleaning-up-user-profiles-in-sharepoint-whose-ad-accounts-are-disabled.aspx